# Opening new window and loading CSS and js from parent window, also share session

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I am building a website and need to open a new window on an image click. I need to take care of following in doing this.

1. I must be able to share session between the two windows, newly opened and parent, that is to say I must be able to work on both windows in parallel and tracking both windows updates in same user session.
2. There are a lot of CSS involved, so is there a way to automatically load all the CSS that has been loaded for parent page in the new window, so that it avoids me from having to load them explicitly again.
3. I need to run a JS where I run an ajax call to populate a table dynamically in the new window, when the new window opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always good to post some code, as it sounds like there's a possibility for a diverse array of options that could be better for your cause than opening a new popup window.

A new window opened with a new URL would have to have it's own CSS, and you couldn't pragmatically just send that over (it'd be much easier to reference it in the head), but if you've referenced the same CSS stlyesheet over the same server it will be cached and not downloaded twice. Nor could you safely send data between them using JavaScript, you would have to use PHP and the global $_POST to safely transfer information and that's definitely the option I'd promote considering I don't know what kind of information you will be transferring. If you want to dynamically load content still, look at JavaScript's AJAX.

Have you heard of modals? These open in the same window, and pop up over the content on that page. They act sort of like a new window, in that the user can enter information, and you can collect information from the same URL. They're on the same page, so they inherit their styles from the parent window's CSS sheets. This is one alternative that, again, because I don't know what you're doing, could be much easier to implement!

Moral of this answer: post what exactly it is you're trying to do, and where you've gotten to. If there is something you don't want to share, share as much as you can without revealing what it is you're protecting. You will much more likely receive a helpful answer this way.

Comment: thanks @Nick. I would have posted the code if i had any ready with me. I am still in phase of understanding how to do this. will update the question with code once i set something solid. I am new to UI dev, and thanks for pointing out about modals, I did not know about it. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for that bootstrap link, i am currently using few of Twitter Bootstrap components so i think i shud be able to wrap my head around it.